# Is there a better way to use Moment with TypeScript (Visual Studio 2019 red squiggly lines)?

Tags: typescript, momentjs, visual-studio-2019

Right now it looks like we have to type a lot:

```
nextTimePeriod(momentString: string) {
    this.today = moment(this.today).add(1, <moment.unitOfTime.DurationConstructor>(momentString + 's'));
    this.startDate = moment(this.today).startOf(<moment.unitOfTime.StartOf>momentString);
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need to add manual types here? Inferred types and not specifying should be sufficient.

Comment: it's giving me red squiggly lines in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Did you followed instructions of [Where to use it => Typescript](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) section of the docs?